# Returning oci error number?

Tags: symfony, pdo, error-handling, oracle-call-interface

i want to execute PL SQL request. I'm using execute() function. I want to handle errors and get an error's number if something went wrong.
i found oci_error manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php but i'm using PDO to connect to my BDD (with symfony2 framework) and i think it doesn't work .

Can you help me?

```
            $conn = "doctrine.dbal.intranet_oracle_connection";

    $sql = "DECLARE message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';BEGIN dbms_output.put_line(message);END;";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt;
////////////////////////////////////////

if ($stmt){ echo "PL OK" } else { echo "Error" : i want the error number here }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Ok i ve shared my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    die("execute() failed!!");
}
return $stmt;
```

Comment: @user2203384 ok, I don't see how you create the connection, you might need to check that also

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late return, i just tested the code today. It doesn't work like i wanted. But i found something that did the job very well, if somebody needs it : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html